# Laravel Auth guard [api] is not defined

Tags: php, laravel

```
Laravel 8.83.19
Passport 10.4
```

Simply started a new project and installed passport and want to use middleware for a route but give this error:

> Auth guard [api] is not defined

**auth.php**

```
'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],
    ],
    'api' => [
        'driver' => 'passport',
        'provider' => 'users',
        'hash' => false,
    ],
```

**AuthServiceProvider.php**

```
 public function boot()
    {
Passport::routes();
}
```

**User Model**

```
use Laravel\Passport\HasApiTokens;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasApiTokens, HasFactory, Notifiable;
...
```

**User Controller**

```
class UserController extends Controller
{
    public function index(Request $request)
    {
        return User::all();
    }
```

**Api.php**

```
Route::middleware('auth:api')->group(function () {
    Route::get('/user/index', [UserController::class, 'index']);
});
```

But when I run `http://localhost:8000/api/user/index` give me:

> InvalidArgumentException: Auth guard [api] is not defined. in file
> D:\Workshop\Other\xxx\xxxapi\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Auth\AuthManager.php
> on line 84

ofcourse I cleared cache:

```
Route::get('/clear', function() {

    Artisan::call('cache:clear');
    Artisan::call('config:clear');
    Artisan::call('config:cache');
    Artisan::call('view:clear');
    Artisan::call('route:cache');

    return "Cleared!";
});
```

By run this:

```
http://localhost:8000/clear
```

Comment: Please try: Route::middleware('auth:api')->group( function () {
  Route::apiResource('/user/index', UserController::class);
  });

Comment: @MartinAmu still same error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your auth.php file must be like this :

```php
<?php
'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],
        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'passport',
            'provider' => 'users',
            'hash' => false,
            ]
    ]
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to clear config cache to take effect. for Unauthenticated it means token is not valid or is not passed correctly

https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/passport#passing-the-access-token

Comment: I already done this, this answer not help me

Comment: why your api array is not in guards array ? 
i mean : 
'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],
        'api' => [
        'driver' => 'passport',
        'provider' => 'users',
        'hash' => false,
    ],
    ],

Comment: @amirrezasalari You are right. That's the problem.

Comment: 'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],

        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'passport',
            'provider' => 'users',
            'hash' => false,
        ],
    ],

Comment: Please up vote my answer bro :D

Comment: @amirrezasalari I don't know, I just installed fresh laravel, I didn't change anything, odd. thanks it fixed my problem, please update your answer with this, I will accept

Comment: @amirrezasalari Please edit your answer to vote up it.

Comment: Ok, I answered to your question in new answer.